# CodeIgniter Pagination

Tags: codeigniter

I after some help with codeIgniter pagination (fixign a bug)..  I can see the number of records and the pagination link in the view but when click on the next link, it does not show the next/previous 10 records.  Can someone please help me with this?

I have the following code in my controller

```
function customerlist_pagination()
{
  $search = $this->input->post('search');
  $data['title'] = "Customer Clist";
  $data['heading'] = "List of customers";
  $data['result'] = $this->customers_model->getAllcustomers_pagination($search_para, FALSE, "limit_rows");
  $data['num_recs'] = $this->customers_model->getAllcustomers_pagination($search_para, FALSE, "num");
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/customer/customerlist_pagination/';
  $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_recs'];
  $config['per_page'] = 10;
  $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
  $config['next_link'] = 'Next &gt;';
  $config['prev_link'] = '&lt; Previous ';
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $this->load->view('customer_view_table',$data);
}
```

In the model, I have the following code:

```
function getAllSeizures_pagination($search_para, $archive_search = FALSE, $result_type)
{   
    $search_para = $search_para."%";
    $selected_fields = "customer.firstName
    customer.lastName, customer.address,
    customer.city, customer.postcode";
    $from = "customer";     
    $where = "customer.deleted=0 ";
    if ($archive_search == TRUE) {
      $where .= "AND customer.archived= 1 ";
    }else{
       $where .= "AND customer.archived= 0 ";
    }
    $where .= "AND (customer.firstName LIKE '$search_para' OR customer.postcode LIKE '$search_para' OR customer.city LIKE '$search_para')";
    $query =  $this->db->select($selected_fields, false)
                    ->from($from)
                    ->where($where)    
                    ->order_by('customer.idcustomer', 'desc');

   if($result_type == "limit_rows") 
   {
      $query = $this->db->limit(10, 0)
                        ->get();
      $query =  $query->result();
   }

    if($result_type == "num") {
         $query = $this->db->get();
    $query = $query->num_rows();
   }

   return $query;
}
```

Thanks alot

Regards
Prats

Comment: How much your records count at your database table?

Comment: it returns 25 which is all records... and the limit is 10

Comment: Well, thats nothing wrong then. If you want showing a sequenced number in your pagination navigation, at least you must have 60 or more records, then adding `$config['num_links'] = 2;` in your pagination config, and everything will goes like you want.

Comment: It doesnt work as how I expected to work though... There are 25 records in total, I am limiting it to 10 records per page... Where am I going wrong not to have the data in the second page?  There should be three pages in total (10, 10, 5) records...

Comment: When you click the `next` link, what url showed up in your address bar.

Comment: First page - http://localhost/customerda/index.php/customer/customerlist_pagination/

Second page when I click Next  - http://localhost/customerda/index.php/customer/customerlist_pagination/10

Third page when I click next -  http://localhost/customerda/index.php/customer/customerlist_pagination/20

Comment: Your uri segment config should be `$config['uri_segment'] = 4;`

Answer (score 0):

The pagination class passes the offset to you in the uri_segment specified. Since you set it to 3, you should capture that info in the first variable of your controller method, like so:

```
function customerlist_pagination( $offset )
{
}
```

Then, when you call your `$this->customers_model->getAllcustomers_pagination()`, you have to pass it the `$offset`, so that later on in your code, where you limit your results:

```
$query = $this->db->limit(10, 0)->get();
```

you should instead use this `$offset` to limit your results:

```
$query = $this->db->limit(10, $offset)->get();
```